# Open Chrome DevTools in app mode window

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I opened a new chrome window in app mode (`chrome --app` command).
And when I pressed F12 to open DevTools, it opened the DevTools in another new window.

So how can I open the DevTools in the app mode window?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the application mode flag `--app` is to run Chrome without toolbars, borders and other browser features that are not part of the web application. Therefore, it makes no sense to provide a dockable version of DevTools. You will need to use the undocked version with the <kbd>F12</kbd> shortcut.